# Function ($ServiceBus) Error: The listener for function 'ServiceBus' was unable to start. Microsoft.ServiceBus: 40400: Endpoint not found

Tags: json, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, servicebus

I have having an issue trying to create a servicebus Azure function in Visual Studio. When I execute the function in VS2017 it works perfectly , however when i publish the message I get the exception:

> Function ($ServiceBus) Error: The listener for function 'ServiceBus'
>   was unable to start. Microsoft.ServiceBus: 40400: Endpoint not found.,
>   Resource:sb://systemmonitordan.servicebus.windows.net/testtopic/subscriptions/catchall.
>   TrackingId:b1a96c67-032c-4c90-bd10-dbac92d11956_G7,
>   SystemTracker:systemmonitordan.servicebus.windows.net:testtopic/Subscriptions/CatchAll.

Here is the function

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace Dan.DataUpdate.ServiceBus
{
    public static class ServiceBus
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection;
        static ServiceBus()
        {
             lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("redisconectionstring")));
        }


    [FunctionName("ServiceBus")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testtopic", "CatchAll", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "ServiceConnections")]string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {

        log.Info($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
}
```

and here are my local.settings.json settings

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dansystemmonito80dc;AccountKey=accountkeystring;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
"AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
"ServiceConnections": "Endpoint=sb://systemmonitortest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=sharedaccesskeystring",
"topicName": "testtopic",
"subscriptionName": "CatchAll"
    }  
}
```

here are the function.Json settings

```
{
  "generatedBy": "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator-1.0.6",
  "configurationSource": "attributes",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "connection": "ServiceConnections",
      "topicName": "testtopic",
      "subscriptionName": "CatchAll",
      "accessRights": "listen",
      "name": "myQueueItem"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false,
  "scriptFile": "../bin/Dan.DataUpdate.ServiceBus.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Dan.DataUpdate.ServiceBus.ServiceBus.Run"
}
```

And Here are my function Application settings

```
AzureWebJobsDashboard DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=danmonitorfunct895c;AccountKey=accountkey

AzureWebJobsStorage DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=danmonitorfunct895c;AccountKey=accountkey

topicName        : testtopic
subscriptionName : CatchAll


    ServiceConnections: 
 Endpoint=sb://systemmonitordan.servicebus.windows.net/
    ;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;
    SharedAccessKey=sharedAccessKey
```

Is there something that i am missing?

Comment: Could this be somehow related? http://pmichaels.net/tag/40400-endpoint-not-found/

Comment: No not related issue

Comment: You're using two different Service Bus connection strings between your test and Azure environments. Does local development work if you try to use your systemmonitordan connection string? Inversely, does Azure work if you use the systemmonitortest connection string?